# How to get count of items present in each category but not present in other categories?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with different visit_types to hospital. They are `Inpatient`, `Outpatient`, `Emergency`

[image]

I would like to know the count of subjects solely present under each `visit_type` but not in other `visit_types`. In the above example the

> Inpatient count - 4
>
> Outpatient count -2
>
> Emergency count - 3

I tried the below but not sure whether it is accurate?

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT PERSON_ID) FROM Visit WHERE PERSON_ID NOT IN 
(select distinct person_id from Visit where visit_type = 'Inpatient') 
AND VISIT_type = 'Outpatient';

SELECT count(DISTINCT PERSON_ID) FROM Visit WHERE PERSON_ID NOT IN 
(select distinct person_id from Visit where visit_type = 'Inpatient') 
AND VISIT_type = 'Emergency';
```

When I do this, it includes common subjects between `Emergency` and `Outpatient`?

How can I get the count correctly?

Comment: can u add the table structure

Comment: @SSMK . . . Your question is quite clear.  But then you add stuff about "Inpatient" as a base category and then include logic about it.  That actually doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Srinathgunnu - Your query will yield the count of patients solely present in emergency type. But how can I get for other types? Should I just repeat the same query twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `CTE` which returns for each `person_id` all the types:

```
with cte as (
  select person_id, 
    sum(case visit_type when 'Inpatient' then 1 else 0 end) Inpatient,
    sum(case visit_type when 'Outpatient' then 1 else 0 end) Outpatient,
    sum(case visit_type when 'Emergency' then 1 else 0 end) Emergency
  from Visit
  group by person_id
)
select 
  case 
    when Inpatient > 0 then 'Inpatient' 
    when Outpatient > 0 then 'Outpatient' 
    when Emergency > 0 then 'Emergency'
  end visit_type,
  count(*) counter
from cte
group by visit_type
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=40156567ffed78ee819577611e5fd7e3).
Results:

```
visit_type | counter
:--------- | ------:
Outpatient |       2
Emergency  |       3
Inpatient  |       4
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know the count of subjects solely present under each category but not in other categories.

You can aggregate by patient, keeping track of the categories.  Then aggregate again:

```
select visit_type, count(*)
from (select patientId, min(visit_type) as visit_type
      from t
      group by patientId
      having min(visit_type) = max(visit_type)
     ) p
group by visit_type;
```

An alternative method uses `group by` but filters before aggregation:

```
select visit_type, count(*)
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.patientid = t.patientid and
                        t2.visit_type <> t.visit_type
                 )
group by visit_type;
```

Note:  In this case, the `count(*)` is counting rows.  If your data has duplicates, use `count(distinct visit_type)`.

I have no idea what "I consider Inpatient category as base category" is supposed to mean, but the question itself is quite clear.

EDIT:

I am unclear on the relationships between the different categories that you want.  You may find it most flexible to use:

```
select visit_type, count(*)
from (select patientId,
             bool_or(visit_type = 'Inpatient') as has_inpatient,
             bool_or(visit_type = 'Outpatient') as has_oupatient,
             bool_or(visit_type = 'Emergency') as has_emergency,
             count(distinct visit_type) as num_visit_types
      from t
      group by patientId
     ) p
where num_visit_types = 1
group by visit_type;
```

This version is the same as the earlier two queries.  But you can use the `has_` flags for additional filtering -- for instance `where num_visit_types = 1 or (num_visit_types = 2 and has_inpatient)` if you want people with one type or one type plus "inpatient".

Comment: what is the `categoryid` column that you have used? My data doesn't have a column like that. I have pasted my table structure above

Comment: When I meant category, I was referring to the `visit_type` values as categories

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query!

```
SELECT 
    C.visit_type,
    COUNT(*) AS count_per_visit_type
FROM (
    SELECT
        person_id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            person_id,
            ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT visit_type) AS visit_type_array
        FROM visit
        GROUP BY person_id
    ) A 
    WHERE LENGTH(visit_type_array) = 1
) B
JOIN visit C
ON B.person_id = C.person_id
GROUP BY C.visit_type
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try. Upvoyted

Comment: Yes, patients can occur multiple times for other visit_types as well. So can you also provide an alternate solution for me to learn? I am trying to run your query step by step to understand

Comment: For example, one subject/patient can be present/occur under `Inpatient` multiple times but not in other visit_types. Similary vice versa is also possible

Comment: In my data, a person_id = 1 only occurs 12 times under `Outpatient` but your query gives incorrect output as multiple outpatient entries of 16

Comment: Updated for you :)